# Parsing XML sometimes returns strange code

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, xml-parsing

I'm parsing a very simple XML document with XCode. Sometimes it works just fine, other times it returns this:

document.cookie='lllllll=9bb65648lllllll_9bb65648; path=/';window.location.href=window.location.href;

Here is my header file:

```
@interface NewsViewController : UIViewController{


NSXMLParser *rssParser;
NSMutableArray *articles;
NSMutableDictionary *item;
NSString *currentElement;
NSMutableString *ElementValue;
BOOL errorParsing;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *newsText;
@property (retain) NSMutableString *theString;

- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL;
@end
```

Here is my implementation code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
 [self parseXMLFileAtURL:@"http://www.domain.com/news.xml"];
}
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
NSLog(@"File found and parsing started");
}


- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL
{

NSString *agentString = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_6; en-us) AppleWebKit/525.27.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.2.1 Safari/525.27.1";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                [NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
[request setValue:agentString forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
NSData *xmlFile = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];


articles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
errorParsing=NO;

rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlFile];
[rssParser setDelegate:self];

// You may need to turn some of these on depending on the type of XML file you are parsing
[rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
[rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
[rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

[rssParser parse];


}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {

NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error code %i", [parseError code]];
NSLog(@"Error parsing XML: %@", errorString);


errorParsing=YES;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
currentElement = [elementName copy];
ElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
    item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

}

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
[ElementValue appendString:string];
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
    [articles addObject:[item copy]];
} else {
    [item setObject:ElementValue forKey:elementName];
    NSLog (@"--%@",ElementValue);
}

}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

if (errorParsing == NO)
{
    NSLog(@"XML processing done!");
    theString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ElementValue];
    NSLog (@"Parsed: %@",theString);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error occurred during XML processing");
}

}
```

I'm fairly stumped, but I'm sure it must be something simple I can't see. Any tips?

Comment: Those text fragments looks like javascript; have you confirmed that every request returns pure XML in the response (you can test this using `wget` or `curl` from the command line)?

Comment: It was working fine, as it was returning pure XML half the time. Weirdly, the results I ended up getting were a result of my host. I relocated the file to a public dropbox link, and it's been working just fine ever since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the response you are trying to parse (probably) is not in XML.

NSLog your xml responses, and see whats being returned by the server when it returns the strange code. Validate the xml before parsing it.

Comment: so at what point do you get the "document.cookie='lllllll=9bb65648lllllll_9bb65648; path=/';window.location.href=window.location.href;"

Comment: It pops up after parsing. Via the log, the code reacts as though it was a success, it just displays that text instead of the correct text that is in the XML document.

Comment: The problem ended up being an issue with the host taking too long to return the datafile. I relocated the file to a public dropbox link, and it's working just fine!